# asp.net Link button image not visible after postback

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a link button with image and label inside it.
After postback, the image and label is not visible.

```
< asp:LinkButton ID="AddNewRunLinkButton" runat="server" CssClass="Navigationlocalnav"
OnClick="AddNewRunLinkButton_Click" >
&nbsp;
  < img id="Img1" src="../../Images/add_newIcon.gif" runat="server" alt="Add New Run" />
  < asp:Label ID="addText" Text=" Add New Run" runat="server"></asp:Label>
< /asp:LinkButton>
```

This link button is used to import/export data. I have added an attribute on click of this link button(AddNewRunLinkButton) to display a progress bar using javascript - SetInterval function.
If I remove this attribute, the image and label is getting displayed, otherwise only link button is getting displayed.

```
AddNewRunLinkButton.attributes.add("onclick","javascript:DisplayProgress()");

function DisplayProgress()
{
  timeid = setInterval("addBlock",100)
}

function Addblock()
{
 // Display a progress bar as follows - Increase the width of a div tag at this interval
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Some code examples would be nice to see if you want some help.

Comment: see the above code snippet...in that image and label is not getting displayed  after postback

Comment: That code wont even display an image in the first place. You really need to give us something more to go on.

Comment: For simplicity could you just copy/paste the markup, code-behind and javascript function? Or atleast the relevant parts.

Comment: What is the AddNewRunLinkButton_Click event doing?

Comment: @Anish, did you managed to solve this issue? I have a similar problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539327

Answer (score 0):

Since your code examples doesn't give much to go on I'm posting something I think might be what you're trying to do.

Markup and Javascript:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var timeID = null;
    var width = 0;

    function DisplayProgress() {
      timeID = setInterval('AddBlock();', 100);
    }

    function AddBlock() {
      var p = document.getElementById("progressDiv");
      if (width < 1000) {
        width += 100;
        p.style.width = width + "px";
      }
      else
        timeID = clearInterval(timeID);
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbAddNewRun" OnClick="lbAddNewRun_Click">
        <img src="--url to an image--" alt="Add New Run" />
        Add New Run
      </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <div id="progressDiv" style="background-color: Green; width: 0px; height: 20px;"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lbAddNewRun.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:DisplayProgress();");
}

protected void lbAddNewRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Export/Import code.
}
```

This does not "hide" the image, for me atleast.

**Remark:**
Instead of adding the OnClick event in the code-behind you can add it directly in the markup since it is not dynamically created:

```
      <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbAddNewRun" OnClick="lbAddNewRun_Click" OnClientClick="DisplayProgress();">
        <img src="--url to an image--" alt="Add New Run" />
        Add New Run
      </asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Hi Sani, The code is more or less similar...other than following differences... 1. I dont use clearInterval, as I want to start from 0, if width reaches 1000. 2. i have an asp:label control after image control ...which contain the text as -"Add New Run" When i looked into the view source...am able to see an anchor tag instead of link button...and nno image and label controls :(.

The timer stops as the postback happens in my case...not using clearInterval..will tat be causing the issue ?

Comment: Could you post the AddBlock javascript function?

Comment: function DisplayProgress(progressDiv) 
{ var progressBar = document.getElementById("ProgressBar"); timerId = setInterval("addBlock('"+progressDiv+"')", 100); } function addBlock(progressDiv) { var progress = document.getElementById(progressDiv); progress.style.align = "left"; var width = parseInt(progress.style.width); if(width < 500) { progress.style.width=width+10+"px"; } else { progress.style.width="0px"; } progress.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'; progress.style.cssFloat = 'left'; progress.style.styleFloat = 'left'; 
}

Comment: I have two divs: ProgressBar which acts as a border for the inner div...Inner Div's width keep on increasing to reach 500px (which is total width of outerdiv - ProgressBar).

Comment: I cannot directly see any problems there that might cause the image to disappear. What are you doing in the AddNewRunLinkButton_Click event?

Comment: I'm executing a serverside function and update a gridview using the result which i get from db side.

Comment: My image tag is having "runat" attribute...and urs is not having the same(is it a typo ?)

Comment: I've used your javascript functions and everything seems to work as intended. The image doesn't disappear. You're not "messing" anything with "img1" or "AddNewRunLinkButton" in AddNewRunLinkButton_Click?

Comment: I've tried both with and without the runat="server" attribute on the img tag and the image displays fine. You could try and remove it since it is not necessary to have it there if you're not doing anything with it in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Async call to show the progress bar as opposed to what you are doing here. Sometime when you attach both client side and server side events, the page rendering doesnt work as expected. In this case you are using a Javascript timer with SetInterval and I believe that is causing the lable to disappear.