# Inner image and text of asp:LinkButton disappears after postback

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonPrint" runat="server" OnClick="OnPrint_Click">
     <img src="img/print-icon.png" alt="" />
     <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:PrintPage %>" />
</asp:LinkButton>
```

In code behind I add an `onclick` handler in `Page_Load` like this:

```
LinkButtonPrint.Attributes["onclick"] = "StartLoadTracking(this, '" + GetLocalResourceObject("Loading") + "')";
```

The rendered HTML is like this:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LinkButtonPrint','')" 
id="ctl00_LinkButtonPrint" onclick="StartLoadTracking(this, 'Loading...');">
    <img alt="" src="img/print-icon.png">Print page
</a>
```

If I click this button it is working OK (it will respond with a PFD file so no HTML is sent back to the browser), but if I click **another** button on the page (which makes a full postback) the `LinkButtonPrint` will not have the inner content, it will be rendered like this:

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$LinkButtonPrint','')"  
id="ctl00_LinkButtonPrint" onclick="StartLoadTracking(this, 'Loading...');"></a>
```

If I remove the `LinkButtonPrint.Attributes["onclick"] = ...` line from `Page_Load` everything works fine (except my js function is not called, but that is normal).

What am I missing here?

**EDIT**
This is duplicate of
[asp.net Link button image not visible after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131510)
but that one is not solved either :(

Comment: It sounds like a ViewState problem. Could you try adding `EnableViewState="false"` to your LinkButton and report back the result?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution:
I had to add `runat="server"` to the `<img>` tag inside the `<asp:LinkButton>`:

```
<img src="img/print-icon.png" alt="" runat="server" />
```

Comment: +1 for sharing the answer. Still, this sounds more like a workaround than like a solution, since the reason for this behavior is still unclear.

Comment: @Heinzi, you are right, I find this too a workaround, but no time for more research, I lost already a couple of hours on this

Comment: Good workaround, but it may pollute the markup if you have many html tags inside the `LinkButton` (eg: `<img>`, `<b>`, `<i>` and so on)..an alternative is the official Microsoft workaround I reported in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11125367/822735), which also includes an official statement from Microsoft about this issue.

Answer (score 37):

This problem is now known to Microsoft, and they have published an official statement and workaround on the [Microsoft Connect issue 718810: LinkButton controls collection lost on postback](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/718810/linkbutton-controls-collection-lost-on-postback).

Microsoft statement is:

> Thank you for the feedback. This seems like an oddity with the fact that the LinkButton control allows either direct text content via the Text property or in markup, or sub-controls via the Controls collection or markup. The workaround is to use a placeholder as the root content for the control and place the desired mixed content in there, e.g.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        This is some text.</br>
        <asp:Label runat="server">This is a control</asp:Label>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: This did not work for me, even after adding the enableviewstate = "false"

Comment: Why do I still support legacy code? This is exactly the problem and solved the issue!

Comment: Thanks!  This solved my issue.  

Note, that the problem was only happening when the link had the status of "Enabled=False".  On postback, it doesn't remember the internal collection of controls.  It does, however remember the text labels in attributes if the content area is empty.

I spent a lot of time digging into this and came up with other working solutions, but did not like them.  The placeholders solution seems to be the cleanest workaround. With the placeholders, the problem is solved and I can move on.

Comment: 2020 and this is still THERE!!!! omg tank you for this, how do you find it? i cant find any info about this right now...

Answer (score 1):

Just a note to add to the solution above.

I found this specifically occuring when I had **enabled=false** (to show disabled style) my linkbutton and then caused a postback from the page via another control.

The .Text component of the linkbutton got wiped out after postback.

BUT by putting runat="server" on my .Text / html tags (em, span), they now are retained after postback.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the **Attributes["onclick"] =** override the handler of the onclick operation.

2 thing you could try :

```
LinkButtonPrint.Attributes.Add("onclick", "StartLoadTracking(this, '" + GetLocalResourceObject("Loading") + "');");
```

or

```
LinkButtonPrint.Attributes["onclick"] = "StartLoadTracking(this, '" + GetLocalResourceObject("Loading") + "');" + LinkButtonPrint.Attributes["onclick"];
```

Comment: The button for which I put a handler worked ok. My luck there was no other `onclick` handler on it.  Thanks for the tip anyway, I'll keep in mind this!